# Possible to select multiple columns from a single CASE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a three boolean columns in a table that determine what values should be fed to a program.  I need to feed up to 3 label and values to my program.

As of now I have a 8 cases for each label and each value (since 3 boolean flags means 2^3=8 combinations).  Is there a way to make it more succinct?

For example, for my first label, I have

```
    case
    WHEN travelExpenseEnabled=0 and otherExpenseEnabled=0 and materialExpenseEnabled = 0 THEN
    ''
    WHEN travelExpenseEnabled=1 and otherExpenseEnabled=0 and materialExpenseEnabled = 0 THEN
    'Estimated Travel Expense'
    WHEN travelExpenseEnabled=1 and otherExpenseEnabled=1 and materialExpenseEnabled = 0 THEN
    'Estimated Travel Expense'
    WHEN travelExpenseEnabled=1 and otherExpenseEnabled=0 and materialExpenseEnabled = 1 THEN
    'Estimated Material'
    WHEN travelExpenseEnabled=1 and otherExpenseEnabled=1 and materialExpenseEnabled = 1 THEN
    'Estimated Material'
    WHEN travelExpenseEnabled=0 and otherExpenseEnabled=1 and materialExpenseEnabled = 0 THEN
    CONCAT('Estimated ', listquotes.otherLabel)
    WHEN travelExpenseEnabled=0 and otherExpenseEnabled=1 and materialExpenseEnabled = 1 THEN
    'Estimated Material'
    WHEN travelExpenseEnabled=0 and otherExpenseEnabled=0 and materialExpenseEnabled = 1 THEN
    'Estimated Material'
    END as optLabel1,
```

And similar for the first value.  This method also means I need to keep my own hierarchy of material > travel > other consistent for each other part of my query, so this will quickly become a headache if I am asked to change order.  Is it instead possible to do something like the following

```
    case
    WHEN travelExpenseEnabled=0 and otherExpenseEnabled=0 and materialExpenseEnabled = 0 THEN
    '' as optLabel1,
            '' as optLabel2,
            '' as optLabel3,
            0.00 as estCost1,
            0.00 as estCost2,
            0.00 as estCost3,
    WHEN travelExpenseEnabled=1 and otherExpenseEnabled=0 and materialExpenseEnabled = 0 THEN
'Estimated Travel' as optLabel1,
'' as optLabel2,
'' as optLabel3,
travelExpense as estCost1,
0.00 as estCost2,
0.00 as estCost3
```

etc for each case.  This way I can set each of the 3 values I need to in just 8 cases, instead of needing to do 8 cases per value.  Is this possible?  I am using MySQL 5.6

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to consider a design where the database logic isn't making decisions about what a UI should display.  Instead, I would return the 3 boolean columns (and any other columns you need) to the UI, and let the UI decide what text will be rendered.  That doesn't solve the succinctness problem, but it does move the logic to the layer where it's more appropriate.

Comment: I completely agree with you in theory.  Unfortunately I have to use this designer software we use to make our own software so my options are limited by it, and this part of a program I am rendering a PDF so a lot of my flexibility is gone.  But I agree.  Normally I would do it exactly like you said.

Answer (score 1):

If you are pulling this from the dB at run time on a UI (I'm assuming) you may wish to flatten your data in advance.

I'd take your code, put that inside a generic select-view, have the app do SELECT {...columnList...} from VIEWNAME where KEY = variable etc

You'll still need to retain & maintain your code base, but it will be centralized in one place.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggests a reference table or derived table:

```
select t.*,
       ref.optlabel1
from t left join
     (select 0 as travelExpenseEnabled, 0 as otherExpenseEnabled, 0 as materialExpenseEnabled, '' as optlabel1 union all
      select 1, 0, 0, 'Estimated Travel Expense' union all
      ...
     ) ref
     on ref.travelExpenseEnabled = t.travelExpenseEnabled and
        ref.otherExpenseEnabled = t.otherExpenseEnabled and
        ref.materialExpenseEnabled = t.materialExpenseEnabled
```

You can include all the labels you want in the subquery.